# Transfer to/into

Tags: prepositions

Let’s say I have some leftovers in a large container and I would like to save space by using a smaller container. Which of the following sentences is appropriate?

1. I should transfer everything ***to*** a smaller container.
2. I should transfer everything ***into*** a smaller container.
   Thank you!

Comment: Both are appropriate. _Into_ merely emphasises that the food is going inside the container, which is the commonsense interpretation anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but "I should transfer everything to a smaller container" is a more commonly used and natural sounding phrase. "I should transfer everything into a smaller container" is also correct, but it may sound a bit more formal or technical. The choice between the two would depend on the tone and style of the writing or speaking context.